# Looking for a manga about a demon lord

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I don’t remember the name of the demon lord but he reincarnates as a young boy with purple(I think) hair and he is really overpowered. I remember him having a true form that looked kind of like a galaxy alien, and had some companions that remember him from before he reincarnated. One part I remember is he’s fighting around a giant sword and a city and has to protect his friends from a giant magic spell.

Comment: What's "a galaxy alien"?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "giant sword"? Is this just combat involving unrealistically large swords that are still used as weapons (like something from Berserk or Monster Hunter), or like a sword-shaped building in the ground?

Comment: The galaxy alien is just the best way I can think to describe him, he looks like he’s see through and full of stars and galaxies with a blueish purple tint. The giant sword is massive, unusable, if I remember correctly the city was on top of the sword or below it. It was in a desert like area.

Comment: I thought it might have been Seiken Gakuin no Maken Tsukai / Demon's Sword Master of Excalibur School, but I'm pretty sure that doesn't include any kind of gigantic sword.

Answer (score 2):

this is [I, the Strongest Demon, Have Regained My Youth?!](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=172402)this is a manga where a galaxy looking entity who had built an  empire and tens of thousands of people submit to him. To get more power he entered the realm of the demons and was looking for the mystery of all lives but in doing so he was gone for thousands of years and his empire is nothing but a market. His name is lauded the demon king